# Running Xamarin.iOS tabbed application in VS2015

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

I installed Xamarin Studio with `Xamarin.iOS` on my macbook (with retina). Created sample iOS tabbed app and it all works great.

Then on VM (same macbook) I installed `VS2015` with xamarin. Created the same sample iOS tabbed app and run it through `Xamarin.iOS Build Host`. It all works but... tab icons are not displayed correctly:/

It should be circle and square:

[image: how it should look]

And I have no circle and square will disappear when clicked :

[image: how it looks when built with VS]

So, my question is: Why is that happening?